# d3.js: Map X-axis labels to some key and render key-label table to avoid overlapping?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Is it possible (it should be possible, I think) to map overlapping X-labels to some key like integer and just render key-label table as the reference? With nvd3.js (d3.js)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you wanted to do just for overlapping labels or for all labels ?

Comment: it's better to be keep consistency. So I'd like to do it for all labels

Answer (score 0):

Here we have converted our data to the following format

```
var data = [ { 
   "key" : "series 1",
   "values" : [
       { xKey : 0 , xLabel : "some big name" , y : "10%" }, 
       { xKey : 1 , xLabel : "some big name" , y : "40%" }
   ]
 }]
```

while generating chart specified which value to be used for x and y axes

```
var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
                .x(function(d) { return d.xKey })
                .y(function(d) { return d.y }) /* This is optional */

d3.select('#chart_element').datum(data)
```

now you have all values in `data` render them in table format as you want.